# Quartz missed jobs is not executing

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, spring-3

I am using Quartz Scheduler with Spring. The version of Quartz is 2.1.6 and that of Spring is 3.1.3.

Here is the configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
    <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>             
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="ldapSynchJob" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="ldapSynchJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="ldapSynch" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 45 0 * * ?" />
    <property name="misfireInstructionName" value="MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_ONCE_NOW" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapSynch" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.edfx.adb.ldap.scheduler.LDAPSynchronizer" />
</bean>
```

I want that, if the server is stopped and restarted and in between if the scheduler missed a job then as soon as server started it will execute the missed job. So I have used persistent storage, Database. But it seems that it is not working.

When I start my server first time I saw in Database, in qrtz_triggers table the column NEXT_FIRE_TIME has value 1356808500000 that means Sun Dec 30 00:45:00 IST 2012. After the execution of scheduler it changed to 1356894900000 which is Sun Dec 31 00:45:00 IST 2012. Then I have stopped my server and changed the system time and set the system time to 31 Dec 12:47AM. Then I again start my server. I was expecting that the scheduler would be executed as soon as the server started as it missed a job. But instead of firing the job the NEXT_FIRE_TIME value changed to 1356981300000 which is Tue Jan 01 00:45:00 IST 2013.

Clearly this is not desired and I am unable to find why this is happening. Any suggestion would be very helpful to me.

The `SessionFactory` that I am using is `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` and the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` has been set to `update`.

### Update

This the class which extends `QuartzJobBean`

```
public class LDAPSynchronizer extends QuartzJobBean {

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        List<Attributes> currentUsersAttributes = LDAPManager.getManager().getCurrentUsersAttributes();
        List<Attributes> pastUsersAttributes = LDAPManager.getManager().getPastUsersAttributes();       
        getLDAPSynchService(context).synchronizeUser(currentUsersAttributes, pastUsersAttributes);
    }   

    private ILDAPSynchService getLDAPSynchService(JobExecutionContext context)  {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;

        try {
            applicationContext = (ApplicationContext) context.getScheduler().getContext().get("applicationContext");
        } catch (Exception e) {         
        }

        if(applicationContext == null) {
            applicationContext = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
        }


        return (ILDAPSynchService) applicationContext.getBean("ldapSynchService");
    }
}
```

### Update

Each time when the server is starting in console I am getting this log:

```
01:28:24,586 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (MSC service thread 1-10) Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.1.6) 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is not clustered.

01:28:24,596 INFO  [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] (MSC service thread 1-10) Quartz scheduler 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
01:28:24,596 INFO  [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] (MSC service thread 1-10) Quartz scheduler version: 2.1.6
01:28:24,596 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (MSC service thread 1-10) JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory@1014d1b6
01:28:24,666 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: SELECT * FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?

01:28:24,706 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: SELECT * FROM QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?

01:28:24,716 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: SELECT * FROM QRTZ_LOCKS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND LOCK_NAME = ? FOR UPDATE

01:28:24,716 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: SELECT JOB_NAME FROM QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND JOB_NAME = ? AND JOB_GROUP = ?

01:28:24,716 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: UPDATE QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS SET DESCRIPTION = ?, JOB_CLASS_NAME = ?, IS_DURABLE = ?, IS_NONCONCURRENT = ?, IS_UPDATE_DATA = ?, REQUESTS_RECOVERY = ?, JOB_DATA = ?  WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND JOB_NAME = ? AND JOB_GROUP = ?

01:28:24,726 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: SELECT * FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?

01:28:24,726 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: SELECT * FROM QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?

01:28:24,726 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: SELECT * FROM QRTZ_LOCKS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND LOCK_NAME = ? FOR UPDATE

01:28:24,736 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: SELECT J.JOB_NAME, J.JOB_GROUP, J.IS_DURABLE, J.JOB_CLASS_NAME, J.REQUESTS_RECOVERY FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS T, QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS J WHERE T.SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND J.SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND T.TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND T.TRIGGER_GROUP = ? AND T.JOB_NAME = J.JOB_NAME AND T.JOB_GROUP = J.JOB_GROUP

01:28:24,736 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: DELETE FROM QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?

01:28:24,736 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: DELETE FROM QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?

01:28:24,736 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: DELETE FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?

01:28:24,746 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: SELECT TRIGGER_NAME FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?

01:28:24,746 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: SELECT TRIGGER_GROUP FROM QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?

01:28:24,746 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: SELECT TRIGGER_GROUP FROM QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?

01:28:24,746 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: INSERT INTO QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP, JOB_NAME, JOB_GROUP, DESCRIPTION, NEXT_FIRE_TIME, PREV_FIRE_TIME, TRIGGER_STATE, TRIGGER_TYPE, START_TIME, END_TIME, CALENDAR_NAME, MISFIRE_INSTR, JOB_DATA, PRIORITY)  VALUES('org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

01:28:24,756 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Hibernate: INSERT INTO QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP, CRON_EXPRESSION, TIME_ZONE_ID)  VALUES('org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0', ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And after that I see `PREV_FIRE_TIME` of QUARTZ_TRIGGERS` table is set to -1. And the number of row is never get exceeded to 1. I don't know if it is normal or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days of studing and searching net, at last I am able to solve the issue. Here is the correct code:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
    <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="ldapSynchJob" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="ldapSynchJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="ldapSynch" />
    <property name="misfireInstructionName" value="MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_ONCE_NOW" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 17 12 * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapSynch" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.edfx.adb.ldap.scheduler.LDAPSynchronizer" />       
</bean>
```

`<property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />` was causing the problem. It was overwriting the `NEXT_FIRE_TIME` value of `QRTZ_TRIGGERS` table.